# Change a list to specific format of JSON

Tags: c#, json, list

I have a list with each item as:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Imagine the list has two items like below (in fact it can have several items)

> Item1 : Name=A / Value=1000
>
> Item2 : Name=B / Value=2000

I want to have a JSON like this:

```
{
    "Date":"2023-11-19",
    "A":"1000",
    "B":"2000"
}
```

Comment: Hi, is it guarantee that the `Name` is unique (will not be redundant), Otherwise it will not be valid for JSON as key must be unique.

Comment: Hi, it's unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.ToDictionary()` to convert the list of objects into a key-value pair (Dictionary).

Based on your output, unsure where is the `Date` comes from. If the `Date` is not appeared in the list and you want it to be appeared in the key-value pair, you need to add the `Date`.

```cs
using System.Linq;

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = items.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);

// Add Date attribute
dictionary.Add("Date", $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd}");
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HnmL2H)

Comment: This does not add the date value OP expect to see in result

Comment: @SelakaNanayakkara The OP doesn't specify where the date is supposed to come from or why it's supposed to be there.

Comment: Hi @SelakaNanayakkara, done adding the `Date` attribute. Thanks for reminding. =)

Answer (score 1):

Please find the attached code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
     public static void Main()
    {
        // Create a list of Item objects
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>
        {
            
            new Item { Name = "A", Value = "1000" },
            new Item { Name = "B", Value = "2000" }
        };
        var additionalProperties = new
        {
            A = "1000",
            B = "2000"
        };
        var mergedObject = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
            mergedObject.Add(item.Name, item.Value);
        }
        mergedObject.Add("Date", "2023-11-19");
        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mergedObject, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
    }
}
```

[image]

> Working .Netfiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/raDJaq)

Answer (score -2):

To convert a list of Item objects into a JSON format as specified, you can use LINQ and Newtonsoft.Json in C# to achieve this transformation.

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Assuming you have a list of Item objects
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Name = "A", Value = "1000" },
            new Item { Name = "B", Value = "2000" }
            // Add more items as needed
        };

        // Create a dictionary from the list using ToDictionary
        var dictionary = itemList.ToDictionary(item => item.Name, item => item.Value);

        // Add Date key with current date to the dictionary
        dictionary.Add("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

        // Convert the dictionary to JSON
        string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);

        Console.WriteLine(jsonResult);
    }
}
```

This code first creates a list of Item objects. Then, it transforms this list into a dictionary where the Name property of each Item object becomes a key, and the Value property becomes the value in the dictionary. Additionally, it adds a "Date" key to the dictionary with the current date.

Finally, it converts the dictionary into a JSON string using Newtonsoft.Json's SerializeObject method, resulting in the desired JSON format:

```
{
  "A": "1000",
  "B": "2000",
  "Date": "2023-11-19"
}
```

This output contains the "Date" key along with the keys/values from the Item objects in the desired format.